# Grid References Third and Sixth Figures

Tags: coordinates, grids-graticules

With Grid References, what can the range be for the third and sixth figures (the tenths of the area squares) be? `1-10`, `0-10`, `1-9` or `0-9`?

So if I had two grid squares like this, where `X` marks the spot:

```
|-----|-----|
|     X     | 1
|     |     |
|-----|-----|
   1     2
```

– would `X` be at `GR019017` or `GR020017`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that it is a matter of rounding. The coordinate should be GR020017 because the x is beyond 0195 and therefore rounded to 020. http://primalevents.co.uk/map-basics-symbols-grid-references-and-contours/